# How to use custom html for y axis labels with formatter in ag line chart

Tags: linechart, ag-grid-angular

How to use custom html for y axis labels  with formatter in ag-grid line charts?

OR how to add background color, height width and other css properties for axes labels?

I tried to use useHTML but it's not working with fortmatter

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.